# Puppeteer inputElement.uploadFile is uploading empty file

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cucumberjs

So, I've hit a snag and can't seem to see where I've gone wrong.
 I'm writing some test automation for a front end emberJS.  I'm trying to upload a file using the browser controls in Puppeteer using CucumberJS.  I've placed a html 5 data-test attribute on the element I want to select.  I have:

```
async selectLinkToImportFile() {
    const inputElement = await this.page.$('[data-test-upload-browse="true"] > input[type=file]');
    await inputElement.uploadFile('./testFileUpload01.csv');
    await delay(2000);
    await this.page.$('[data-test-button-begin-import="true"]');
}
```

This seems to work, the file is selected, but it's size is 0.00 MB which I know to be incorrect.   Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

My solution:

```
// Upload a Payment file from Dashboard
async selectLinkToImportPaymentFileAndSecelectFile(filename) {
    await listener.startAsync();
    if (await page.waitForSelector('[data-test-upload-browse="true"]')) {
        const inputElement = await page.$('[data-test-upload-browse="true"] > input[type=file]');
        if (filename === 'test_payment_file_valid_01.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/test_payment_file_valid_01.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'test_payment_file_valid_02.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/test_payment_file_valid_02.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'test_payment_file_valid_03.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/test_payment_file_valid_03.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'autolWorkflow_PaymentRequestShelf_MatchedSupplier.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/autoWorkflow_PaymentRequestShelf_MatchedSupplier.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'autolWorkflow_PaymentRequestShelf_UnMatchedSupplier.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/autoWorkflow_PaymentRequestShelf_UnMatchedSupplier.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'FC_Political_File.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/FC_Political_File.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'supplierDataMinimumAddACHData.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/supplierDataMinimumAddACHData.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'supplierDataMinimumRemoveACHData.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/supplierDataMinimumRemoveACHData.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'supplierDataAchBellin_Remove.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/supplierDataAchBellin_Remove.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'supplierDataAchBellin_Add.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/supplierDataAchBellin_Add.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'automaticWorkflow_paymentFile_01.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/automaticWorkflow_paymentFile_01.csv`);
        }
        else if (filename === 'automaticWorkflow_paymentFile_03.csv') {
            await inputElement.uploadFile(`${__dirname}/../../test_files/automaticWorkflow_paymentFile_03.csv`);
        }
        else {
            debug(`ERROR: Filename '${  filename  }' not a valid selection`);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out.  I should be more patient

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: Thanks for keeping me honest David.

Comment: @HuckleberryCarignan I believe David is nudging you to post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help future visitors who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript , I did the following based on the relative file path.

```
 import { resolve } from 'path';

public  getValidFileToUpload(): string {
         return resolve('src/assets/validDemoFiles/bulkDemoFile.csv');
     }
public get chooseFile() : Promise<ElementHandle> {
        return this.page.$(this.uploadFileSelectors.chooseFile);
    }


public async uploadBulkFile() : Promise<void> {
        await this.page.waitForSelector(this.uploadFileSelectors.chooseFile);
        const fileHandle = await this.page.$('#csvFileUpload');
        await fileHandle.uploadFile(this.getValidFileToUpload());
      // button click to upload file
        await this.uploadButton.then(e => e.click());
    }
```